# Go Back in Visual Studio Code when Testing Links in Markdown Preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

What's the easiest way to get back to where I came from after visiting an internal document link using Visual Studio Code's Markdown Preview?

Alt+[minus], Alt+[leftArrow], Alt+[backspace] and [backspace] don't seem to work for me.

**UPDATE March 8, 2023: Ctrl+Alt+- acts like it is trying to take me back to where I left off, but it ends up putting me in some seemingly random location [1]. This is possibly due my copious use of display hogging image files.**

[1] -
"Navigate back: Ctrl+Alt+-" 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_navigation-history

Comment: As far as I can tell, a bookmark extension is the best way to handle this right now:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179571/are-there-bookmarks-in-visual-studio-code I think Warren P (user:84704) also mentions customizing the keys when using a bookmark extension.

Comment: It's been a year and a half and this still seems broken. I'm now using EMACS as a local web-server with impatient-mode to get around this issue. The EMACS method allows me to preview my markdown changes almost instantly in a real web browser so I can use Alt+Left_Arrow (and other features) for easy navigation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183071/how-can-i-preview-markdown-in-emacs-in-real-time

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way to get back to the preview of the original markdown file is to click in editor for the md file, this doesn't always work, in which case I usually end up closing the preview & re-opening it. This works well enough for me as I usually have the editor & preview side-by-side.

Comment: Seems that would work, but when I visit an internal link via the preview window, it shifts both the preview window *and* the md editor to the new location. For this reason, clicking in the editor window doesn't do me any good because the editor window is *already* at the new location and doesn't remember where I was.